# Reading C program's output files in javascript

Tags: javascript, c

I'm trying to connect two programs I wrote- one is a c program that outputs files to my local disk and the other is a web program that's supposed to show the content of this files on screen by reading them from my disk. I've tried different methods to read those files but it all failed.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you when you don't show us how the files are written? They could be in any of a 1000 formats, or none at all.

Comment: Little detail given, but Javascript won't allow you to open files if they don't "belong". Otherwise a Javascript in a web page could read your whole drive. It's a security issue.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/369817).

Comment: Several common browsers support `FileReader` (fro example Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader but not IE, as it seems)

Comment: @WeatherVane He could use Node.js and run a local server that has access to these files. (in that case use the module ‘fs‘ and maybe a filewatcher)

Answer (score 0):

You can't read it in JavaScript because it doesn't have access to whatever is in your filesystem, so you could either make your C program output the files with HTML markup and append to the same HTML file or put your web app on a server and use a backend technology (like Apache & PHP) to interpret those files and display them however you want.

Comment: Server-side Javascript has full filesystem access. Javascript isn't just for browsers anymore.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Yeah, PHP its just a suggestion.